# Erro de segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c++11, c++14

Bom dia a todos, como estão?

Tenho um problema para resolver em linguagem de C++:

"Codifiquem, em C, um programa de adição de vetores. O tamanho N do vetor deve ser um argumento da linha de comandos na chamada ao programa. Utilizem um gerador aleatório (rand) para criar os vetores A e B, definidos como tipo float. O vetor C, também float, deverá guardar o resultado da soma: C = A + B. Mostrem no final a soma de todos os elementos de C."

Depois de pesquisar, consegui fazer o código que era necessário, o problema é o seguinte: Quando eu dou valores de N acima de 700 000 o programa dá o seguinte erro - "segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Tive a pesquisar e vi que era um problema de alocação de memória, o problema é que eu não sei como resolver este problema, visto que não tenho capacidades suficientes em C++.

Será que me podiam ajudar?

Abaixo deixo-vos o código.

Obrigado pelo vosso tempo!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { //Estes parametros permitem ao programa receber argumentos da linha de comandos
                         //argc guarda a quantidade de parametros
                         //argv vai guardar os endereços de memória dos inputs dentro de uma matriz


// 1 - Receber o tamanho do vetor
char *c = argv[1]; // Receber o valor de N como um char
int n = atoi(c); // Para depois converter para int


// 2 - Criar dois vetores com valores aleatórios e tamanho n
float A[n], B[n]; // Vetor A e B

srand(time(NULL)); // Gerar números aleatórios do tipo float

int i; // for

int tamanho = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]); // Obter o tamanho dos vetores (o tamanho é igual para todos)

// Preencher o Vetor A com valores float entre 1 e 100
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++) 
{
    A[i] = rand() % 100 + 1; // rand() % max + min;
}


// Preencher o vetor B com valores float entre 1 e 100
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    B[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;
}


// 3 - Somar os dois vetores e guardar o resultado da soma no vetor C
float C[n]; // Criar o vetor C

for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}


// 4 - Mostrar a soma de todos os elementos do vetor C
int soma = 0; // Variavel que vai guardar a soma

for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    soma+=C[i];
}
printf("A soma dos elementos do Vetor C é %d.\n",soma);







/*
// VERIFICAÇÃO DE RESULTADOS
// Verificar os valores do vetor A
printf("VERIFICAÇÃO DE RESULTADOS:\nVetor A\n");
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    printf("Indice: %d --> Valor: %f \n",i,A[i]);
}

// Verificar os valores do vetor B
printf("Vetor B\n");
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    printf("Indice: %d --> Valor: %f \n",i,B[i]);
}

// Verificar os valores do vetor C
printf("Vetor C\n");
for (i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
{
    printf("Indice: %d --> Valor: %f \n",i,C[i]);
}
*/


return 0;
}
// O programa foi compilado numa máquina virtual Ubuntu com 8GB de RAM (Visto que é o objetivo do trabalho)
// Compilar Programa: gcc nome_ficheiro.c -o nome_output
// Executar Programa: ./nome_output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possivelmente você está estourando a sua capacidade de memória, pois vejo que não está acessando uma posição indevidamente.

Veja só:

> um float ocupa 4Kb.
>
> Usando o tamanho de vetor de float com 700 mil posições, são 700000 x
>   4Kb = 2800000Kb = 2.8Gb.
>
> Multiplicando por 3 vetores: 2.8 x 3 = 8.4Gb.
>
> Provavelmente a sua capacidade de memória RAM é de 8Gb.

Se for um problema pra faculdade, não se preocupe, seu código está bem feito e correto.

Caso seja um projeto pessoal ou queira aumentar o tamanho do vetor, você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
Aloque apenas o vetor A; 
preencha ele por completo;
Imprime A (apenas por critério de verificar a validade do código).
Aloque vetor C;
Copie A por completo para C (C vira uma cópia exata de A);
Desaloque A por completo;
Aloque B;
Preencha B;
Imprima B;
Some o conteúdo de C com B ( C[i] += B[i]);
Imprima C;
```

Dessa forma você reduzirá para 2/3 a quantidade de dados guardados em memória.

Answer (score 0):

Use o o último core dump gerado para fazer a análise:

```
gdb programa core_dump
```

Use os comandos abaixo para extrair informações úteis para a análise:

```
bt
bt full
info threads
thread apply all bt
thread apply all bt full
```

Caso seu problema seja mais complexo, voce pode usar esta biblioteca google que permite gerar core dump em seu próprio código:

```
https://code.google.com/archive/p/google-coredumper/
```

Comment: Ao executar o meu programa não me aparece o ficheiro que contém o core dump, e pelo que tive a pesquisar, para usar o gbd necessitamos desse ficheiro para fazer a análise.

Comment: O local de gravação pode variar dependendo de sua dist. linux, mas tente estes caminhos: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/, [/proc/sys/kernel/]core_pattern, /var/spool/abrt/,

Answer (score 0):

Muito provavelmente o problema foi causado por "estouro de pilha".

Variáveis locais (isto é, declaradas dentro de uma função) normalmente utilizam um espaço de memória chamado de "pilha" (comumente também chamado de "stack" mesmo em português). O tamanho desta "pilha" é fixo para cada programa, e 1 MB é um valor comum.

A solução no caso é criar os arrays em memória dinâmica através da função "malloc". Memória alocada através da função "malloc" não está sujeita às restrições do tamanho da pilha.

```
// 2 - Criar dois vetores com valores aleatórios e tamanho n
// float A[n], B[n]; // Vetor A e B
float* A = malloc(n*sizeof(float);
float* B = malloc(n*sizeof(float);
```